# Python based on .txt file

Tags: python, linux, txtextcontrol

I own a txt file that contains many lines Each line will be as the next

```
email1:password1
email2:password2
...
...
...
emailxx:passwordxx
```

I want a python code that reads the file line at a time Where the next is printed

```
email=username1
pass=password1

email=username2
pass=password2

email=username3
pass=password3
...
...
...
email=usernamexx
pass=passwordxx
```

Comment: Where the usernamexx come from ? And does the password is always password and id (I guess it's the ID) of the user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks i fixed it

```
with open("xxx.txt") as f:
for line  in f.readlines():
   #print(line)
   values = line.split(":")
   email = values[0]
   pasw = values[1]
   print(f"user={email}\npass={pasw}\n")
```

Comment: you don't need to `close()` when you use `open()`

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
with open('path/to/file.txt','r') as f:
    values = f.readline().split(":")
    print(f"email={values[0]}")
    print(f"pass={values[1]}\n")
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ss.py", line 3, in <module>
    f.write(f"email={values[0]}\n")
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable

Answer (score -1):

the open functions gives you a file object and has methods to read the lines from the file.

```
with open(filepath) as f:
    for line  in f.readlines():
       print(line)
       info = line.strip(":"))
       output = f"email={info[0]}\npass={info[2]}"
       print(output) 
f.close() #Close the file when you're done.
```

Comment: with `open()` you don't need to `close()`. In addition, why to `readlines()` if you can `readline()`

Comment: readlines does one opertation instead of asking for each line individually.